# Correctness of the solving method of a limit

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I want to find the following limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}{[\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})]}$
So I solve it with the method after:
$$-1\le\sin(\frac{1}{x})\le1\iff\begin{cases}-\sin(x)\le\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})\le\sin(x), & \text{if $\sin(x)>0$} \\ -\sin(x)\ge\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})\ge\sin(x), & \text{if $\sin(x)<0$}\end{cases}$$

- $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{[-\sin(x)]}=0=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{[\sin(x)]}$$
  So:
  $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{[\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})]}=0$$
  With the same method:
  $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}{[\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})]}=0$$

And then:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{[\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})]}=0=\lim_{x\to 0^-}{[\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})]}\iff\lim_{x\to 0}{[\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})]}=0$$

Is my method right? And if not how to find this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct but little long.

For $x\ne 0,$

$$|\sin (\frac {1}{x})|\le 1 \implies$$

$$|\sin (x)\sin (\frac {1}{x})|\le |\sin(x)|$$

$$\implies$$
$$ -|\sin (x)|\le \sin (x)\sin (\frac {1}{x})\le |\sin (x)|$$

now squeeze.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your method seems correct to me.

You can also use: $$|\sin{x}| \leqslant |x|,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
combining the fact that $$-1 \leqslant\sin{\frac{1}{x}} \leqslant 1,\forall x \neq 0$$